# Como colocar tags em um textbox pelo Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Tentei com o Bootstrap da seguinte forma:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Modal Dialog -->
<div class="modal fade open" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" >
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"  aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblModalTitle" runat="server" Text="Enviar arquivos"></asp:Label></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUp" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server" />
                <br />

                Tag:<asp:TextBox ID="tbTag"  runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn ui-icon-cancel small" ID="UpluodButton" OnClick="UploadButton_Click" Text="Enviar" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

E o seguinte *script* no `<head>`:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#<%=tbTag.ClientID%>').tbTag({
            autocomplete: {
                source: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'violet', 'brown', 'purple', 'black', 'white'],
                delay: 100
            },
            showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
        });
    }
</script>
```

Mas não funciona.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Referencia: http://jquery-plugins.net/tokenfield-jquery-tag-token-plugin-for-bootstrap

Comment: Como você está referenciando o Bootstrap e o Tokenfield?

Comment: E as referências do Tokenfield que você está querendo utilizar?
Abra o console do navegador, e verifique se apresenta algum erro.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: no javascript la, pois ta dentro do head, abaixo das referencias dos js.

Comment: o erro da na linha : $('#<%=tbTag.ClientID%>').tbTag({

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22133/discussion-between-war-lock-and-paulohdsousa).

Comment: coloquei e agora aparece issso: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade  pq apagaram a resposta?

Comment: qual a outra forma que vc disse que resolvia?

Comment: não sei dizer porque apagaram a resposta. E não acompanhei, para saber o que se tratava a resposta.

Comment: tu falu do  ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbTag, coloco aonde?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22139/discussion-between-renilson-andrade-and-war-lock).

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade como assim referencias do Tokenfield? o que é isso?

Comment: ja referenciei o tokenfield e nada

Comment: @WarLock O erro por não fechar `$()` no código Javascript foi causado no momento de colar o código aqui na pergunta?